# how to get distinct value from an array javascript

Tags: javascript

how can i get elements uniquely from an array if aa is twice time it should not count in a result if it is if a is three times it should count 1

var string = "aaabbccddde" // Expected result ade

```
var toArray = string.split("")
console.log(toArray)
var newArr = []
for(let i =0; i<toArray.length; i++) {
    if(newArr.indexOf(toArray[i]) === -1) {
        newArr.push(toArray[i])
    }
}

console.log(newArr)
```

can't find the solution yet please guide thank

Comment: Are repeating characters always next to each other? If not, what logic would you want when not?

Comment: why do you count the last `e`?

Comment: I just want if values are two times it should not countable on other hand all should be countable

Comment: new Set("fooooooood"); /// 'fod'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this function can help you:

```js
function getUniques(str) {
    const uniques = [];
    const strs = str.split("");

    for (let i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        const elm = strs[i];

        for (let j = i; j < strs.length; j++) {
            if(elm === uniques[uniques.length - 1]) break;

            if (elm !== strs[j + 1]) {
                uniques.push(elm);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return uniques.join("");
}
```

Sample:

```js
getUniques("aaaadaaabbbcccdeeeee22222222222232") // adabcde232
```